# Probability of two vowels from the word MATE if two letters are chosen at random, without a replacement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My textbook seems to have given me an answer without explaining. It states that the answer is 1/6 but it's a four-letter word, someone please explain. :)

Comment: Do you know anything about permutations,combinations?

Comment: Considering that I am in year 9, no I do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There $4$ choices  to draw the first letter because there are four possible letters.  Once you draw the first letter there will be three letters left and so there will by $3$ choices  to draw the second letter.

That means there are $4*3 = 12$ ways to draw two letters.

If you don't trust that, you can count them out.  The first letter can $M,A,T,E$.

If it's $M$ the second letter can be $A,T,$ or $E$. and you could draw $MA, MT$ or $ME$.  $3$ ways.

If the first letter is $A$ the second letter $M,T,$ or $E$.  $AM, AT,AE$.  $3$ more ways.

Then $TM, TA$ or $TE$.  $3$ more.

And finally $EM, EA,ET$.  $12$ ways total.

Now in order to draw two vowels there are $2$ choices for the first vowel: $A$ or $E$.  And for the second vowel there will only be one vowel left to be the second one.

So there are $2*1 =2$ ways to draw two vowels.  Namely:  $A$ then $E$.  And $E$ than $A$.

So of the $12$ total ways to draw two letters, there are $2$ ways to draw to vowels.

So the probability is  $\frac 2{12} = \frac 16$.

Answer (score 5):

There are six ways to choose two letters from the word:

```
MAte MaTe MatE
mATe mAtE maTE
```

but only the choice of `A` and `E` results in two vowels. The probability is thus 1/6.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple. There are four letters in the word but actually there the sample space is 12 because 2 letters are choose . And event given is to be AE hence probability is 2/12=1/6

Answer (score 0):

The word has 4 letters. Two of them are vowels so there is a 2/4 chance that the first pick will be a vowel.

That would leave three letters, containing one vowel, so there is a one in three chance that the second pick will be a vowel.

```
2/4 * 1/3 = 2/12 = 1/6
```